# how to install Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell Optiplex 745?

Tags: 16.04, dell

I have found only the ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso that does not work: I have made a DVD containing the *.iso content as I am used to do with 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04; booting with the DVD starts to apply Ubuntu but instead of asking about trying or installing Ubuntu it shows only an empty, colored display and nothing but switching off the PC is possible. I wonder if the problem cannot be connected with a graphics driver (I have a monitor connected to the native computer graphics, not to  an embedded PCI graphics card, the type of which I do not know). Thanks!

Comment: No, nothing to do with it. `amd64` is for all 64bit CPUs, from Intel, AMD or other. What "does not work"exactly? And why are you mentioning monitor and graphics? Please edit your question and describe what you did, what were the intended results and what happened instead.

Comment: @CelticWarrior: Similarly, the CPU "freezes" by booting with the 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04 (in one of them it "freezed" after my anwer ~'try Ubuntu'). With Windows XP, the CPU works OK for watching and recording TV.

Comment: Again, use 64bit only. Although 32bit also works in 64bit hardware it is not recommended. Also prefer newer releases. Also prefer USB, if available, instead of DVD. Assuming it **doesn't have an addon (discrete) graphics card -and -the hardware is in good working condition** it should just work.

Comment: Should I dismount the now unused PCI graphics card? (Yesterday, I have changed connecting the monitor to the native graphics, because, with old CPUs mentioned in my profile, installing Ubuntu 12.04 was not possible when I used an addon PCI graphics card.) The Dell Optiplex 745 CPU did not boot properly from USB.

Comment: If it's unused then what's the point in having it? Now, it should also work with with the additional card (**please post all hardware info**) but it may require additional steps and also may require changing some settings in BIOS.

Comment: @CelticWarrior: Thanks, tomorrow I will dismount the addon card, try it again and let you know.

Comment: If you post the exact specs of that card I'll be able to suggest something.

Comment: Dismounting the unused PCI graphics card has not helped. Now I try to get and run a full Dell diagnostic for the Optiplex 745 CPU.

Comment: Dell diagnostic Version 1337A0 is running; up to now, no error has appeared.

Comment: I gave it off and I buy the Dell Optiplex 7010.